# Firestore (Datastore mode) - how many writes are billed if a transaction is rolled-back?

Tags: google-cloud-datastore

Can anyone shed some light on how billing works in **Firestore (Datastore mode)** when a transaction is rolled back? How many writes is one going to be billed if one batch deletes 500 entities (DeleteMulti) then rolls back the transaction?

Comment: considering that the 500 entities were deleted successfully?

Comment: @JanHernandez, I am confused. For the entities to be deleted successfully, the transaction needs to be committed and I have yet to work with a database allowing committed transactions to be rolled-back. My scenario is based on the assumption that one rolls-back instead of committing.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From a billing/quota perspective, operations are tracked exactly the same in a transaction regardless of whether the transaction succeeds and is committed, or rolled back.

This means that if a you attempts to create 5 items, then delete 2 existing ones, then create one more, they will be charged for 6 write operations and 2 deletes. This will be the case if the whole transaction succeeds, or if the transaction fails on any of the individual operations, even if those operations are never committed and do not appear in the data after the transaction has been rolled back.

So answering your question, **you would be billed for 500 deletes**, regardless of whether the transaction succeeds or is rolled back.